# JSON.NET deserializing derived classes does not work as expected

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have been searching the forums and the JSON.NET website on this issue and from what I can see I'm correctly following the guidelines but it is not working correctly.

I'm trying to deserialize object from derived classes. 
Serializing works fine, but when deserializing it tries to deserialize in to the wrong type.

I'm trying to do this with Windows Phone 8 and JSON.NET 4.5.11

I have the following classes which I am serializing:

```
public class MyClass : ModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public MyAction Action {get; set; }
}



public abstract class MyAction : ModelBase
{
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public abstract ActionType ActionType { get; }
    public abstract void Execute();
}

public class SettingsAction : MyAction 
{
    public override ActionType ActionType
    {
        get { return ActionType.Settings; }
    }

    public SettingsType SettingsType {get; set; }

    public override void Execute()
    {

    }
}

public class NoneAction : MyAction 
{
    public override ActionType ActionType
    {
        get { return ActionType.None; }
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I serialize it like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass 
{
    Action = new SettingsAction()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                obj, 
                Formatting.Indented, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(json);
}
```

And it gives me the following JSON:

```
{
  "$type": "Model.MyClass, Model",
  "Title": null,
  "Action": {
    "$type": "Model.SettingsAction, Model",
    "SettingsType": 0
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, this is correct, I told it to include the type information and it's correctly included.

The I deserialize it like this:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
}
```

And I get the following error:

**JsonSerializationException: Error setting value to 'SettingsType' on 'Model.NoneAction'**

So, although the type is contained in the JSON, on serializing it's ignoring it and of course deserializing it into a different type fails.

Does anyone have an idea why it's not taking the information into account and deserialize to the correct type?

Comment: Have you tried using the same `JsonSerializerSettings` on your `DeserializeObject` call?

Comment: Yes, I tried that right after posting the question, but to no avail, still the same error.

Comment: What is `<T>` in `DeserializeObject<T>`?

Comment: I removed some of the details when posting the question and I forgot to take this out, but essentially it's just MyClass. I edited the code to make it clearer.

Comment: I've got it working in a plain console app running under Windows 7, using Json.Net v4.5.11 and .Net Framework v4.5.  I had to make a couple of assumptions about the code since you do not have `ModelBase`, `ActionType` or `SettingsType` defined in your example above.  I also took out the streaming since it did not seem to be relevant to the question.  The code is posted here: [http://pastebin.com/RMtcjZb2](http://pastebin.com/RMtcjZb2).  Can you try to run that in Windows Phone 8 and see if you still have an issue?

Comment: If it runs, that would mean there must be some other detail or difference in your code that is causing the issue.  If it does not run, that would seem to point to a difference in the Windows Phone environment.

Comment: Hi, I actually did the same thing. The code shown is a simplified version of what I have in the app. I simplified it to be able to show it. The simplified version runs perfectly in fact (on windows phone). I guess I simplified the problem away. Strange thing is that the JSON inside the real app, does contain the type info but still tries to deserialize to the other type. I'm going to gradually add more things from the application until it happens in the sample as well. Thanks for your time anyway. Once I've got the problem I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the culprit:

In one of my properties I was doing this:

```
public MyAction Action
{
    get 
    {
        if (_Action == null) {
            Action = new NoneAction();
        }
        return _Action; 
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Action)
        {
            _Action = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Action");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the getter, where I create a NoneAction if the obejct is null.
Apparently Json.NET calls into the getter at some point between creating the MyClass object and setting the values of the MyAction object. When it sees that the Action-property is not null, it tries to assign the values instead of overwrite the whole object.

Comment: Makes sense.  I am glad you were able to find the problem.